# Adding event in Angular Boostrap UI Calendar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel, fullcalendar, angular-ui-bootstrap

We are trying to build a Reservation Management System made with laravel/angular. We used angular bootstap ui in this [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) . We are trying to build an app without using JQUERY.

But in this case,We need to use a Calendar. I dont know if Angular bootstrap calendar doesn't support the event like in this [page](http://fullcalendar.io/) .

Is there a link/documentation where i can add an event using angular bootstrap  ui calendar? or i really need to use jquery plugin to achieve this feature?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Comment: Build a Plunker or get more specific on the question.  Angular can respond to the events in the FullCalendar.io but because they are initiated not in an Angular context you have to use a special pattern to ensure the Angular app responds correctly.  Try something out, post a Plunker and I can help.